# Unique base class instance

Tags: database, singleton, radix

I'm developing a C++ dll that containts three classes: say base class `Base`, `Derived1` and `Derived2` class.
The scenario:

```
class Base
{
   //ctor, dtor, members and methods here
}

class Derived1 : public Base
{
   //ctor, dtor, members and methods here
}

class Derived2 : public Base
{
   //ctor, dtor, members and methods here
}
```

The dll I'm creating with MS VC++ 2008 Express, that I want to use under Turboc++ (borland:
very good ide/rad).

I export `Derived1` via facotry method, and via client code, `Derived1` makes instances of `Derived2`. Both `Derived1` and `Derived2` share a pointer function contained in another dll, so I put that pointer function under Base class.

Here is the problem. Once time I create one instance (via factory) of `Derived1` and it can create multiple instances of `Derived2`, the `Base` class constructor is called more times (1 for `Derived1` and multiple times for `Derived2`).

How can I prevent multiple intances of Base?

**A further question:**

With the scenario I described earlier, `Derived1` call multiple intances of `Derived2` and both `Derived1` and `Derived2` extends unique common base class. I ask: It is a bad design? Is there another design of classes and their inheritance hierarchy better than what I used?

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent multiple instances of Base. You can prevent multiple instances of the pointer - make it static:

```
class Base {
    public:
        // save first pointer I get passed
        Base( sometype * p ) {
            if ( myptr == 0 ) {
               myptr = p;
            }
        }

    private:

       static sometype * myptr;
};
```

In a C++ source file you will need to define myptr:

```
sometype * Base::myptr = 0;
```

Comment: Since every instance of Derived* is to the Base::Base() ctor an instance of Base, you can't really prevent multiple instances of Base, because you absolutely need them. Neil is absolutely right about making the functionPtr static to solve your problem.